# img tab visibility is coming as blank

Tags: html, css

In HTML there is this tag :
  `<img id="img-1" src="image.jpg" alt="random" width="300" height="168"/>`

In javascript code if I do : 
`var x = document.getElementById("img-1");`
`console.log(x.style.visibility)` --> this displays as ""

In my css I have specified -

```
img {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Not sure why its picking up "" as visibility

Comment: Maybe try checking if the element is already loaded before any javascript?

Comment: @Daweed that's not the problem. If that were the problem, you would get a `Cannot read property style of undefined`  error , x ( the element ) being undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementCSSInlineStyle/style). It returns the styles applied to the element including from external stylesheets

> The Window.getComputedStyle() method returns an object containing the values of all CSS properties of an element, **after applying active stylesheets** ...

[`element.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementCSSInlineStyle/style) returns only the inline styles applied to it . eg `<img style="visibility: hidden;" .... />` would've been returned by element.style.

> The style read-only property returns the **inline style** of an element in the form of a CSSStyleDeclaration object that contains a list of all styles properties for that element with values assigned for the attributes that are defined in the element's **inline style attribute**.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("img-1");
console.log(x.style.visibility, window.getComputedStyle(x, null).visibility)

/*or for IE <9 compatibilty use
const visibility = window.getComputedStyle ? getComputedStyle(x, null).visibility : x.currentStyle.visibility;*/
```

```html
<img id="img-1" src="image.jpg" alt="random" width="300" height="168"/>
```

Comment: Is there way to do it simply. Like specify the style in html tag itself

Comment: more ' simply ' than this ? :) well if you specifiy the `visibility: visible` inline on the element itself, then yes. you can access it with `element.style.visibility` . Not sure i understand your question. In my answer you should have everything you need